# Property 'preferredDatePickerStyle' not found on object of type 'UIDatePicker'

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker, react-native-ios

I am using react-native 0.62.2 version and datetimepicker version 3.0.1. As I am trying to build the project with xcode, the following errors are being shown:

1. Use of undeclared identifier 'UIDatePickerStyleCompact'
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'UIDatePickerStyleWheels'
3. Property 'preferredDatePickerStyle' not found on object of type
   'RNDateTimePicker *'
4. Property 'preferredDatePickerStyle' not found on object of type
   'UIDatePicker*'
5. Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id' is
   disallowed with ARC
6. Statement requires expression of integer type ('__strong id'
   invalid)
7. Implicit conversion of 'UIDatePickerMode' (aka 'enum
   UIDatePickerMode') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
8. Use of undeclared identifier 'UIDatePickerStyleWheels'

The following is the code inside **RNDateTimePickerManager.h**

```
#import "RNDateTimePickerManager.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import "RNDateTimePicker.h"
#import <React/UIView+React.h>

@implementation RCTConvert(UIDatePicker)

RCT_ENUM_CONVERTER(UIDatePickerMode, (@{
  @"time": @(UIDatePickerModeTime),
  @"date": @(UIDatePickerModeDate),
  @"datetime": @(UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime),
}), UIDatePickerModeTime, integerValue)

RCT_ENUM_CONVERTER(UIDatePickerStyle, (@{                //Error 5
    @"default": @(UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic),
    @"compact": @(UIDatePickerStyleCompact),             //Error 1
    @"spinner": @(UIDatePickerStyleWheels),              //Error 2
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000
    @"inline": @(UIDatePickerStyleInline),
#endif
}), UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic, integerValue)

@end

@implementation RNDateTimePickerManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [RNDateTimePicker new];
}

+ (NSString*) datepickerStyleToString: (UIDatePickerStyle) style {
    // RCTConvert does not handle this.?
    switch (style) {                                       //Error 6
        case UIDatePickerStyleCompact:
            return @"compact";
        case UIDatePickerStyleWheels:
            return @"spinner";
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000
        case UIDatePickerStyleInline:
            return @"inline";
#endif
        default:
            [NSException raise:@"Unsupported style value" format:@"UIDatePickerStyle of %ld is unsupported", (long)style];
            return @"";
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getDefaultDisplayValue:(NSDictionary *)options resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIDatePicker* view = [RNDateTimePicker new];
        
        view.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;          //Error 4
        UIDatePickerMode renderedMode = [RCTConvert UIDatePickerMode:options[@"mode"]];
        view.datePickerMode = renderedMode;
        // NOTE afaict we do not need to measure the actual dimensions here, but if we do, just look at the original PR
        
        UIDatePickerMode determinedDisplayValue = view.datePickerMode;    //Error 7

        resolve(@{
                 @"determinedDisplayValue": [RNDateTimePickerManager datepickerStyleToString:determinedDisplayValue],
                });
    });
}

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(date, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(locale, NSLocale)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(minimumDate, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(maximumDate, NSDate)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(minuteInterval, NSInteger)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onChange, RCTBubblingEventBlock)
RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(mode, datePickerMode, UIDatePickerMode)
RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(timeZoneOffsetInMinutes, timeZone, NSTimeZone)

RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(textColor, UIColor, RNDateTimePicker)
{
    if (@available(iOS 14.0, *) && view.datePickerMode != UIDatePickerStyleWheels) {  //Error 8
    // prevents #247
    return;
  }
  if (json) {
    [view setValue:[RCTConvert UIColor:json] forKey:@"textColor"];
    [view setValue:@(NO) forKey:@"highlightsToday"];
  } else {
    UIColor* defaultColor;
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        defaultColor = [UIColor labelColor];
    } else {
        defaultColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    [view setValue:defaultColor forKey:@"textColor"];
    [view setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"highlightsToday"];
  }
}

// TODO vonovak setting preferredDatePickerStyle invalidates minuteinterval
RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(displayIOS, UIDatePickerStyle, RNDateTimePicker)
{
    if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
        if (json) {
            UIDatePickerMode propValue = [RCTConvert UIDatePickerStyle:json];
            view.preferredDatePickerStyle = propValue;           //Error 3
        } else {
            view.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Is there any bug in the react-native datetimepicker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who are still stuck on this, specifically using [this](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker) library.

Starting from version 3.0.3, it require that your Xcode is at least v11 but they never mention that v11.3 will not work which a lot of people already noticed that you will need at least v11.6.

Mind you, downgrading might not really help you either as you're missing the point of update which addresses a lot of bugs e.g [#217 fix](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker/pull/217)

Answer (score 3):

you can use latest stable XCode (11.6).

Comment: Really random issue. But updating Xcode v11.3 to v12.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer for this is to update xcode to at least v11.6. I have been on solving issues around this for more than 48 hours and at end when the app finish building successfully, i battled missing dependencies.