# How do you upgrade XCode in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: xcode, macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With the recent [prolific problems](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/212096467) with Azure DevOps' `macOS-10.15` and `macOS-latest` [agents](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1241137/azure-pipelines-builds-are-cancelled-on-macos-agen.html) one of the solutions to get around the problem at least my Expo build was to use the `macos-10.14` agent which is all well and good.  However, in my Cordova project I am using a plugin that uses `UIDatePickerStyleWheels` which is [resolved by an XCode update to 11.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592410/property-preferreddatepickerstyle-not-found-on-object-of-type-uidatepicker)

I was wondering how do you [upgrade XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617452/how-to-update-xcode-from-command-line) within an Azure DevOps pipelines.  Especially since the agent is headless I can't just enter a password or access the App Store to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you mentioned that you use latest stable XCode (11.6) and it works as expected.

Now the [issue](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/212096467) with MacOS 10.15 Hosted Agents seems to have been fixed, I am using macOS-10.15 and it works fine. You can try MacOS 10.15 again.

In addition，you can add Xcode task in Azure DevOps pipelines, then select **Specify path** in the "Xcode version" option list, and then specify the path in the "Xcode developer path" option as: **/Applications/Xcode_11.6.app**. You need to note that the "SDK" option type **iOS 13.6**.
[image]
[image]